# "Esperar" mientras se realiza una tarea

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo una aplicación de escritorio que he desarrollado con Python 3.6 y Tkinter que hace ciertas tareas. Por temas de confidencialidad no puedo contar que hace exactamente ni publicar código.

Cuando tiene que realizar alguna tarea que tarde algunos segundos (entre 5 y 10 seg) la aplicación se queda 'colgada' como si hubiera petado, pero realiza la tarea y muestra los resultados correctamente. Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar al usuario un tipo de ventana o alguna animación como por ejemplo: 'Generando Informe en PDF...' para darle mas información pero no se me ocurre como hacerlo.

Un saludo, gracias.

Comment: Las tareas que consumen mucho tiempo no debes ejecutarse en el hilo de la GUI, asi que lo primero que debes hacer es ejecutar esa tarea en otro hilo.

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto:https://stackoverflow.com/a/31358712/5215609

Comment: @eyllanesc Actualmente estoy haciendo esto para ejecutar una tarea en segundo plano al iniciarse la aplicación: t = threading.Thread(target=cargar_dataframe, args=("File.xlsx",))
        t.start() Pero ralentiza muchísimo la ejecución de la aplicación, hay otras formas de hacerlo?